# Sum of subarray multiplied by last element of subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array find all sub-arrays and multiply it by last element of sub-array and  find summation .

E.g : [1,2,3]
ans = 1*1 + 2*2 +3*3 + (1+2)*2 + (2+3)*3 + (1+2+3)*3 = 53

I've tried following logic:

```
init_sum = sum (array)
prev = array[0];
ans = 0
for i = 1 to n:
ans += array[i]* array[i]*(init_sum-prev)
init_sum -= prev
prev = array[i]
end loop

ans += sum(array)
print(ans)
```

But this does not work for array with repeated elements

E.g : [1,3,3] , I'm getting ans = 88 where it should be 70.

Any hint would be appreciated .

Comment: Could you explain about your formula? and about the [1,3,3] case too? a little bit confused about the result.

Comment: formula is pretty simple , i've traced it out for [1,2,3] and it gives correct answer 53. But in [1,3,3] , because of repeated 3s  I'm not getting right answer.

Comment: Your formula is only correct your [1, 2, 3], otherwise, it will be wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a recursive formula for each element of the array.

For each element ith, we can notice that the contribution of this element to the overall sum is equaled to the sum of all sub array that end at this element times the value of this element itself.
I.e

For array `data[a, b, c, d]`, the result will be:

```
result = a * a
       + ((a + b) + b) * b
       + ((a + b + c) + (b + c) + c) * c
       + ((a + b + c + d) + (b + c + d) + (c + d) + d) * d
```

Call the factor to be multiplied with the value of ith element is `xi`, we make one observation that

```
xi = x(i - 1) + i*data[i]
```

So, in case of the above array

```
x1 = a
x2 = ((a + b) + b) = x1 + 2*b
x3 = ((a + b + c) + (b + c) + c) = x2 + 3*c
x4 = ((a + b + c + d) + (b + c + d) + (c + d) + d) = x3 + 4*d
```

Thus, we have our solution

```
init_sum = 0
ans = 0
for i = 0 to n:
    init_sum = init_sum + (i + 1)*array[i]
    ans += init_sum*array[i]
end loop

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are after can be divided into the following steps:

1- Generate the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the given array.

2- For each set, add each element in the array, pick the last element in the current set and add multiply it with the sum of the set. Add this `sum` to the `totalsum`

Lets see this in action for [1 3 3], I use the algorithm below to generate the power set and store it in `res`

Step 1:

```
void generateSubsets(int i, vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& holder, vector<vector<int>>& res)
{
    if(i >= nums.size())
    {
        res.push_back(holder);
        return;
    }

    holder.push_back(nums[i]);
    generateSubsets(i+1,nums,holder,res);

    holder.pop_back();
    generateSubsets(i+1,nums,holder,res); 
}
```

Where I call this function as:

```
vector<vector<int>> res;
vector<int> holder;
vector<int> nums = {1,3,3};
generateSubsets(0,nums,holder,res);
```

The generated subsets in `res` are:

```
[1 3 3],[1 3],[1 3],[1],[3 3],[3],[3]
```

Step 2 : Add each element in the set and multiply by last element of the set, so we have.

`[1+3+3]*3 + [1+3]*3 + [1+3]*3 + [1]*1 + [3*3]*3 + [3]*3 + [3]*3`

Cumulative `totalsum` will then be:
`totalsum = 21 + 12 + 12 + 1 + 18 + 3 + 3` = `70`